# Landscape for patch management at scale

Tags: landscape

I have an environment with 5000+ servers in different networks. I am planning to install Landscape to manage the patching process.

It is possible to install multiple Landscape servers to load balance the support of 5000 + clients (Like Red Hat satellite and Capsule)?

One master Landscape server and multiple slave servers in each network?

Comment: Are you saying that the servers you wish to manage using Landscape are in completely isolated networks? There is no federated support like you describe.

Comment: Servers are in multiple subnets , but can talk to each other . I want to have one master Landscape server and seperate slave type of landscape in each subnet to manage the load .

Answer (score 1):

Landscape can scale-out the components of a single server to deal with scale, and has been tested well beyond the 5,000 managed device mark, so the size of your environment is no issue.

Landscape does not have a federated master/slave multiple server architecture. Landscape's architecture scales out the internal components of a single server instead. Landscape can leverage multiple external package repositories for package delivery, you could think of that as conceptually similar to Satellite 6 with multiple Capsule servers delivering updates.